# How to add filter to group_by query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to find number of level of specific type in database.

```
for l, c in session.query(Player.level, func.count(Player.level)).group_by(Player.level).all()

# how to add condition Player.type==1
```

I have seven different type for player and I have 10 levels.
I need to get number of players by level which are only type=1 (not to list all seven)

How to add filter to this query  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about appending this:

```
filter_by(type=1)
```

All together:

```
for l, c in session.query(Player.level, func.count(Player.level)).\
                          group_by(Player.level).filter_by(type=1).all()
```

Comment: all() is not necessary

Comment: OMG I'm confused with Django ORM, sorry ))

Comment: all() coerces the result into a list. It does exactly the same as when you call `iter(query)` or `[for result in query]`: Thus you can omit it, it does not make much difference as it returns the same result either way. Normally, you don't need the `all` at all. It's like generators: The only reason you coerce them into a list is usually only to print it or similar: `print query.all()` (or `print list(query)` for that matter)